# Test if PFFile array is empty

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have an array that starts out empty but is filled with PFFiles (image data) with a PFQuery. A UIImageView has its image set using the data in the PFFile Array. However, if the array is empty then there is an error saying array index is out of range. Therefore, I need something testing to see if array is empty and I can't find a way to do that.

```
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
```

And then in the `viewDidLoad`

```
self.imageFiles[self.imageCounter].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{
    (imageData, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        self.mainPic.image = image

    }else {

    }   
}
```

I would like to be able do something like:

```
    If let testVariable = self.imageFiles[self.imageCounter] as PFFile {

    }
```

Or more simply:

```
If self.imagesFiles[self.imageCounter] == nil {

}
```

But neither of those work

Comment: Check if imageFiles.count is greater than zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're going out of the bounds of the array, as you said. You can void this by checking the size of the array *before* trying to access an element. The following should do the trick:

```
if (self.imagesFiles.count > self.imageCounter) {
    //myImage = self.imageFiles[self.imageCounter];
}
```